# Does Solarian gravity boost function exactly like spider climb?

Tags: starfinder

It says at level 6 you can move along walls as per the spider climb spell. Does that mean it functions exactly like the spell or is it only using it as a reference? For instance do you gain climb speed 20 or do you just use your speed? Also as per the last part "If you end your movement while you are standing on a vertical surface or ceiling, you fall unless you succeed at an Athletics check to climb to remain in position." What DC is this based on?  Do you just make a check with the skill still active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It works as the spell

[Gravity Boost](https://www.aonsrd.com/StellarRevelations.aspx?ItemName=All):

> You can increase or reduce the gravitational attraction between yourself and the terrain around you. You can add a bonus equal to one-third your Solarian level (minimum +1) to Athletics checks to climb, jump, or swim as part of the action you take to attempt the skill check. In addition, as a reaction when you are falling, you can reduce the falling damage you take by half. **At 6th level, you can move along vertical surfaces and even upside down along ceilings for 1 round. This functions as spider climb, but it leaves your hands free and you can also run. You must end your movement on a surface that can support you normally. If you end your movement while you are standing on a vertical surface or ceiling, you fall unless you succeed at an Athletics check to climb to remain in position.**

[Spider Climb](https://www.aonsrd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spider%20Climb&Family=None):

> The target can climb and travel on vertical surfaces or even traverse ceilings as well as a spider does. An affected creature with four limbs must have three limbs free (not holding equipment or being used to perform skills and so on) to climb in this manner. A creature with six limbs needs only four available. In general, other creatures must have 75% of their limbs available to benefit from this spell. **The target gains a climb speed of 20 feet** (and the +8 racial bonus to Athletics checks to climb granted by that climb speed); furthermore, it doesn’t need to attempt Athletics checks to climb to traverse a vertical or horizontal surface (even upside down). An affected creature climbing in this way is not flat-footed while climbing, and opponents get no special bonus to their attacks against it. The creature, however, can’t use the run action while climbing.

As is the case with all abilities that call out spells to "work as", Gravity Boost gives you all of the benefits of the Spider Climb spell for one round until you stop moving (which would always be by the end of your turn). On the Solarion's turn, they function as having Spider Climb cast on them, so they get the 20 ft climb speed, +8 to Athletics for climb related checks, and can traverse vertical walls and ceilings. In addition, Gravity Boost lets you do this climbing without using any more limbs than your legs. When you end your movement, the effect ends for the round.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this:

> Gravity Boost
>
> [...] At 6th level, you can move along vertical surfaces and even upside down along ceilings for 1 round. This functions as spider climb, but it leaves your hands free and you can also run. You must end your movement on a surface that can support you normally. If you end your movement while you are standing on a vertical surface or ceiling, you fall unless you succeed at an Athletics check to climb to remain in position.

**Yes, this ability work exactly as per the "spider climb" spell.**

As a general rule; **everytime** you see something like this "This functions as spider climb" it means it works exactly as the mentioned spell/feat/ability (usually every difference is written in the same text like in this case where it states you can have hands free etc etc)